# How to create a time loop series in R

Tags: r, loops, time

My group and I recently started working with R but have however ran into a problem with creating a time loop series for about 15,000 entries. We want it to be from 00:00 til 23:59 for all entries so we're able to calculate each one of them. We were thinking of creating a separate column for time but have no idea how that's done for 15,00 entries.

Sample data:

`df = data.frame( id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),  Timeoutside = c(08:30:46.000, 07:20:18.000, 07:46:08.000,    07:27:44.000), Timeinside = c(13:36:40.000,     10:04:40.000, 11:59:05.000, 12:22:05.000)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
n = 15000
ans <- seq(as.ITime("00:00"), as.ITime("23:59:59"), length.out = n)
#"00:00:00" "00:00:05" "00:00:11" "00:00:17" "00:00:23" "00:00:28"
# ...
# ...
# ...
# "23:59:30" "23:59:35" "23:59:41" "23:59:47" "23:59:53" "23:59:59"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, would you mind clarifying it a little as we are still beginners. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading the helpfiles of `?seq` and `?data.table::asITime`.